# how do i get firebase current time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I've tried that code below,and i got an error of cannot read property of undefined TIMESTAMP.

```js
firebase.database().serverValue.TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Try this "Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP"

Comment: that one didnt work

Comment: but i tried firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP and it worked thanks anyway

Comment: That's great :) then you need to close the issue by answer it and give a green tick to it.

Comment: before i close the issue. on my console i get this :s:"timestamp" instead of the actual time. what could be missing?

Comment: Proper syntax is `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`